# How to change parent state from child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I'm learning react.js and try to do something like this:
I have NumberBox component with NumberLink child components.

NumberBox has `val` state.

NumberLink has `val` property.

When I click NumberLink I'd like to change NumberBox state to link's `val` property, but in console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onNumberLinkClick is not a function.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ym58zcv4/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `undefined` for the `onNumberLinkClick` prop.

Use the second argument to [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to provide the `this` value when the callback is executed:

```
var numberLinks = this.props.data.map(function (number) {
  return (
    <NumberLink val={number} key={number} onNumberLinkClick={this.handleNumberLinkClick}/>
  );
}, this)
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ym58zcv4/3/

---

Using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) will turn cases like this into runtime errors so they're easier to catch.

You could also use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (which preserve the current value of `this` automatically) by enabling the React JSX transformer's `harmony` mode, or using [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) as your transpiler:

```
var numberLinks = this.props.data.map(number =>
  <NumberLink val={number} key={number} onNumberLinkClick={this.handleNumberLinkClick}/>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were also setting the state round the wrong way in your `handleNumberLinkClick` function

`this.setState({val:number})` should be `this.setState({number:val})`

https://jsfiddle.net/andykenward/6m3wp3kr/